# How to update extended User Model using Django Forms?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and need a help.

I want to allow users to update their account data using form, but struggle with associating Django User model with my UserProfile model, which extends default model with some additional fields.

I found, that solution is to create my own model form, but unfortunately I'm not exactly sure how to implement it.

**models.py:**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    city = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password',
            'image',
            'city'
        )
```

**views.py:**

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)
```

**edit_profile.html:**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are looking for [Inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). Just read the docs, it's pretty simple.